# Accessing a local variable after "delete this"

Tags: c++

I have a class that employs a reference counting mechanism. The objects of this class are eventually destroyed by calling `delete this` when the reference count drops to zero. My question is: can I use local on-stack variable after `delete this`? Here's a more specific example:

```
class RefCountedClass
{
public:
    RefCountedClass(Mutex& m) :
        mutex_(m)
    {}

    .
    .
    .

private:
    Mutex& mutex_;

    void RemoveReference()
    {
        // As I understand, mutex_ will be destroyed after delete,
        // but using m is all right because it is on-stack and
        // references an external object. Am I right?
        Mutex& m = mutex_; 
        m.Acquire();

        --recount_;
        if (refcount <= 0) delete this;

        m.Release();
    }
};
```

Comment: Having objects reference count themselves is a bad idea (Can it tell if it is a static lifespan (stack) or dynamic lifespan (heap) variable?. This is how COM works and from the experiences gained by the C++ community we have moved on; as can be seen from boost::shared_ptr where the reference count is not part of the object being referene counted.

Comment: @MartinYork I agree with you. In a general case I wouldn't advise myself to implement such reference counting. This is a special case though. Fortunately, in my real situation, the constructor isn't public and the creation is protected by a factory object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, [you may do this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this), *as long as* the member variable itself is really only a reference to an external object.

(Please forgive the previous wrong answer, I was confused about the `mutex_` variable.)

Comment: +1 from me. I overlooked what was assigned to the local variable. I like your answer better, so I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but why not to use atomic decrement instead of decrementing the counter under the mutex? And do you actually need to protect (by mutex) object destruction? Indeed, after counter becames 0 the only current thread can acess the object.

So, maybe it is possible to rewrite your code as

```
     int tmp_count;
     m.Acquire();
        tmp_count= --recount_;
     m.Release();
     if (tmp_count <= 0)  delete this;
```

(or use atomics to decrement and test the counter)

Comment: **Dangerous**! This may double-delete since you test for `tmp_count <= 0`. It would be safe to test for `== 0` instead. But this example beautifully illustrates why concurrent code is so hard to get right.

Comment: It's dangerous if the program contains some another bug
(recount_ can not be <0 otherwise); but generally I agree that
 == is more acceptable in this case.

+1 about concurrent code. Time spend to analize and verify such a code may be 10..20..50 times greater than time spend to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the only thing you are not allowed to call after `delete this` is anything that makes a reference to `this`. This include any non-static class member or function.

In your case, there is a good chance that `RemoveReference` will not work. This is becuase `m` points to `mutex_` which no longer exists after delete this. Your best bet could well be making `mutex_` static.

**Edit:** Although `mutex_` points to an external variable which continues to exist after the class is deleted, there is no bulletproof guarantee that the compiler will not refer back to `mutex_` after the class is deleted to obtain the value of the external mutex. There is a good chance that things will work as expected but I do not believe this can be guaranteed.

Comment: No, `m` points not to `mutex_` but to whatever `mutex_` points to: notice that `mutex_` is a reference itself!

Comment: See my edit - I am assuming that a reference is treated as a pointer but being a reference, the compiler may cache the value of mutex_ and have things work as expected.

Comment: If the compiler does what you speculate it might, it is broken. This is legal C++. Put another way -- how it this situation different to `int a=myIntegerMemberVariable_; delete this; doSomethingWith(a);`? Isn't it pretty clear in this case that any compiler that "optimizes" this to `doSomethingWith(this->myIntegerMemberVariable_);` is broken?

Answer (score 0):

Yes in this case. Your stack variable 'm' points to an external resource that you get in the constructor