# After using 'delete this' in a member function I am able to access other member functions. Why?

Tags: c++, linux, oop, this-pointer

I just wrote a sample program to see the behaviour of **delete this**

```
class A
 {
   ~A() {cout << "In destructor \n ";}
 public: 
    int a;
    A() {cout << "In constructor \n ";}

    void fun()
     {
       cout << "In fun \n";
       delete this;
       cout << this->a << "\n"; // output is 0
       this->fun_2(); // how m able to call fun_2, if delete this is called first ??
     }

   void fun_2()
    {
      cout << "In fun_2 \n";
    }

main()
{
 A *ptr = new A;
 ptr->a = 100;
 ptr->fun(); //delete this will be executed here
 ptr->fun_2(); //how m able to execute fun_2 when this pointer is deleted ??
 cout<< ptr->a << "\n"; //prints 0
 return 0;
}

> Output
In constructor
In fun
In destructor
0
In fun 2
In fun 2
0
```

**Questions**

1. After executing **delete this** in fun(), how I am able to access func_2() with this pointer in fun() ??
2. Now in main how I am able to do **obj->fun_2** as this pointer is deleted ??
3. If I am able to access function members after killing this object, then why data members are comming zero '0' ??

*m using linux ubuntu and g++ compiler*

Comment: It's *undefined behaviour*. There's little point asking why something specific is the case, since *anything* could legitimately happen.

Comment: "After driving faster than the speed limit, I was still able to continue driving". You broke the law, buddy. You were "lucky" that nothing happened, but you still broke it. There's nothing in the C++ standard that says "once an object has been deleted, all accesses to the object must be detected and reported as errors".

Comment: You can access memory off the end of an assigned buffer, too. In both cases, behaviour is undefined. So Don't Do That.

Comment: Incidentally, you may find it edifying to run your program through Valgrind and see what it has to say.

Comment: +1, It may be undefined behaviour but it reveals some interesting details about how `g++` implements things.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422625/accessing-a-local-variable-after-delete-this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866461/why-should-i-not-try-to-use-this-value-after-delete-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's compare that to a similar szenario:

```
A *a= new A();  
func(a);  
delete a;  
func2(a);
```

In my sample the compiler just passes the pointer a to func and func2, it does not care if it is pointing to a valid object. So if you call `func2(a)` and func2 dereferences the pointer, this is undefined behaviour. The program might crash if the memory was released back to the operating system and the program cannot access *a anymore. Normally delete keeps the memory allocated, does not pass it back to the operating system, so accessing *a after delete will not give an exception, but just return any value. This might be the previous values of *a, but it might also be any other value depending on the implementation of delete and depending on other calls to new done between `delete a` and `*a`. MSVC for example sets the memory to a predefined pattern in debug mode so you can easily spot when accessing freed memory.

Why is this related to your question? Because the compilers passes `this` as a hidden, implicit parameter.

Answer (score 9):

1. What you see is undefined behavior: it might work, or it may crash.
2. The pointer is pointing to a deleted instance - it is a dangling pointer.
3. This is an undefined behavior as well: you may see a zero or a garbage value.

[Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) provided a very nice "book in a table drawer of a hotel room" analogy in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/335858) to a question about pointers to local variables after the function has returned, it is equally applicable here.